# Python sys.argv auto-escaped my arguments from command line?

Tags: python, linux, shell

I am trying to build a script needs the power from 'grep' in linux shell.
However, I found Python sys.argv escaped my regex pattern from command line.
For example, I am going to pass '\d' as grep pattern from command line.
But the string returned by sys.argv[1] was escaped as '\\d'

I did the following test under debug mode:

```
#SyntaxTest.py
import sys
  #other stuff preventing my debugger from stopping after importing

#shell
python3 -m pdb SyntaxTest.py '\d'

> /cygdrive/d/PythonSandBox/SyntaxTest.py(1)<module>()
-> import sys
(Pdb) n
(Pdb) sys.argv[1]
'\\d'
(Pdb) print(sys.argv[1])
\d
```

I wonder why Python needs to escape my command line argument and I am asking a way to get a plain, un-escaped string in my example.

## EDIT

It's impressive that '\\d'=='\d'.
But in my circumstance, I need to pass the string into subprocess like this.

```
>>> pattern = '\d'
>>> str = r"echo '%s'"%pattern
>>> str
"echo '\\d'"
>>> subprocess.check_output(str,shell=True)
b'\\d\n'
```

It's obvious that \\d has been passed to shell. However, I need it to be just \d instead of \\d. Is there any way other than substitute manually?

Answer (score 2):

That's just how the Python interpreter prints strings. Your `print` call shows that the string isn't really escaped.

```
>>> '\d'
'\\d'
>>> '\\d'
'\\d'
>>> print('\d')
\d
>>> print('\\d')
\d
```

Notice also that `'\d'` and `'\\d'` are two ways of writing the same string.

```
>>> '\d' == '\\d'
True
```

Comment: Python isn't turning `\d` into `\\d`. If you want to see what's literally in a string look at the `print` statements. Those are the ones to trust. See how they print `\d` not `\\d`.

Answer (score 2):

Python hasn't escaped your shell argument. This is how the backslash character is represented because backslash is the escape character, so in order to be **literally used** in the string, it has to be escaped.

For example, you must be aware that `print '\n'` will print a newline character

```
// Python REPL:
>>> print 'a\nb'
a
b
```

If you want to print the **literal** *\n* string, you must escape the backslash character with another backslash:

```
// Python REPL:
>>> print 'a\\nb'
a\nb
```

So a doubled backslash is just the way that a **literal** backslash is represented in a Python string (and I guess in almost all programming languages, as this is sort of a standard).

For more information see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character

Comment: I believe I understand what is escaping. But I am not sure if this is compatible with other language. For example, as my experience using Perl, I don't remember I've found this difficult.

Comment: Perhaps the issue is that when Python's REPL displays the return value of a string expression, the output will be formatted in the same way that the string is represented as source code in Python itself.

I don't know how Perl handles this, but different REPL's for different languages might use different conventions when displaying values returned from expressions.

Python's REPL will differentiate raw output from return values in the way they are formatted. AFAIK return values are always expected to be formatted in a way that they can be directly inserted back into source code.